# The same script in PHP in localhost doesn't working online

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, database-connection

I upload my script in my server and I made a new database in the same server.

the connection with database is working, but when the two script check or insert new value on the database doesn't working, but in localhost yes!!

```
    <?php
    require 'client/facebook.php';

    $app_id = "***";
    $secret = "***";
    $app_url = "***";

    // Create our Application instance
///jump the code
    ////////////////////////////////
    $sdb   = "***";
    $db = "***";
    $userdb = "***";
    $passdb = "***";

    $dblink = mysql_connect($sdb,$userdb,$passdb);
    $seldb = mysql_select_db($db);

    $username = $username;  //user data
    $UIDfaceboook =$id;  //UID USER FACEBOOK FROM API
    $user_type ="aa";  //USER DATA

    $connection ="";  //variable for start function check UID
    $checkUIDdb ="INATTESA";  //check if exist the UID facebook 
    $insertnewuser ="";
    $loadspecific ="inattesa";

    ///
    ///CHECK CONNECTION WITH DATABASE
    ///

    $mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($sdb, $userdb, $passdb);
    if (!$mysqlConnection)
    {
      echo "NO DATABASE FOUND, CHECK USER, PASS, DB";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connection with database is            ";
        echo $connection = "ok";
    mysql_select_db($db, $mysqlConnection);
    }

    //////////////////////////THIS FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK ONLINE
    if ($connection = "ok"){

    $con=mysqli_connect($sdb,$userdb,$passdb,$db);
    $check="SELECT * FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = '$UIDfaceboook'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($data[0] > 1) {
        echo "UID IN THE DATABASE         ";
        echo $checkUIDdb = "found";
    }

    else
    {
            echo "UID IN THE DATABASE         ";
            echo $checkUIDdb = "nofound";
        }


    }

     ///////////////THIS FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK ONLINE, and doesn't insert values
    if($connection == "ok" && $checkUIDdb == "nofound"){

         $username = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($username));
         $UIDfacebook = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($UIDfaceboook));
         $user_type = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($user_type));
         $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db`.`tabletest` (`id`,`username`,`UIDfacebook`,`user_type`) VALUES ('','$username','$UIDfaceboook','$user_type');");

         if($sql){

              //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
              echo $connection = "SAVE USERNAME, UID FACEBOOK AND USER TYPE ON DATABASE";

              echo $loadspecific ="caricadati";
              echo $insertnewuser = "yes";

         }else{

              //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.

         }

    }else{
        echo $connection = "       CORRECT LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK";

    }

        mysql_close($dblink);

        //Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
     ?>
```

the echo php on my server said " connection with database is okUID IN THE DATABASE nofound" so, I don't understand when the variable $connect, $checkUIDdb is working don't load the script for insert a new user... I try to add my UID facebook in my database to check if the script jump this step, but the script ignore the database... just said that...

maybe the first problem is on $check="SELECT * FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = '$UIDfaceboook'";

but in localhost works..

thank you very much, i don't know what I can do...

Comment: Have you given proper values for DB variables within your server?

Comment: mysql_and mysqli_ are not the same and dont mix.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `mysqli` functions like `mysqli_connect()` and `mysqli_select_db()` here.

Comment: thank you all, I resolve the problem with the database and the If condition, i don't know why the php code didn't make any error about the value in the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first error i saw was this one:

```
    //////////////////////////THIS FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK ONLINE
if ($connection = "ok"){
```

i guess you should edit this to

```
if ($connection == "ok"){
```

so you ask if $connection has the value "ok" and not if the allocation of "ok" to $connection has been done successfully.

Second error could be a mixture of "mysql" and "mysqli"...

hth